# Create Document Set if it does not exist (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, document-set

Adding If doc set does not exist then create doc set. What would be the syntax for looking up document set then create (if does not exists)

```
### Create new Document Set
$siteURL="http://intra.colgate.com/sites/vendors"
$docLib = "SOA"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder($docLib).Files
$count=$collFiles.Count
while($count -ne 0)
{
$item = $collFiles[$count-1].Item
    $DocSetName = $item["Vendor"]
    $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($list.RootFolder,"Document Set Title",$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
```

Comment: Did you guys change the site look n feel? Is it still a php site?

Comment: our beta design is gone as of tonight as we soon will be moving out of beta. Please keep this kind of comments on [meta](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm answering the right question, but I used this method to check if Doc Set (folder) exists, and if not, create:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $rootWeb.GetFolder($targetDocLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/$docSetName")

if (-not $targetFolder.Exists)
{
    # create
}
```

This approach worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. I will try it tomorrow. Thanks again