# Creating document sets from a spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, document

I have a list of offices that I need to create document sets for using a custom document set content type. Anyone have any idea how to create a Powershell script to read the spreadsheet and create the document set?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access [Excel Services with PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191201(v=office.14).aspx) and read your data. Then you need to [Create a document set](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/create-document-set-if-it-does-not-exist-powershell) from that data. This is not an easy task. I would consider other alternatives.